# Picking properties of a map from a list in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there a way to pick properties of a map from a list in elixir?

```
map = %{
  a: 1, b: 2, c: 3
}

do_something(map, [:a, :b]) = %{a: 1, b: 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Map.take/2:

```
iex> Map.take(%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, [:a, :b])
%{a: 1, b: 2}
```

Comment: Ya just saw that in documentation. Thanks!